# In php's fsockopen() findout user's port number

Tags: php, port, fsockopen

How to find out the port number on the user's machine from which the connection is made?

Comment: What connection are you talking about? The connection to the webserver? (likely 80, or 443).

Comment: No, i mean which port in my server is being used to connect to port 80,443 of the target server.

Answer (score 1):

`fsockopen` returns a stream resource.  I've searched through the PHP documentation and can't find a way to get the client port from the stream resource.

However, if you go one level lower and use sockets you can easily get at this info.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, 'stackoverflow.com', 80);
socket_getsockname($socket, $host, $port);
var_dump($port);
socket_close($socket);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running the netstat command.

```
netstat -an
```

Answer (score 0):

It's available as part of the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) super global

```
$port = $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'];
```